# make a general "where" clause on MS access Formulaire

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

guys i have a table named "Authors" and i want view all auhors borned on the avril (04/2002) and then make view them how to do that on formulaire ?  im a newbie sorry .

Answer (score 0):

I think we've got a slight language problem.  By "on formulaire" do you mean you are looking for an SQL statement (in other words, "formulaire" means "SQL statement")?  That would just be

```
SELECT * FROM [Authors] WHERE [DateOfBirth]>=#4/1/2002# AND [DateOfBirth]<=#4/30/2002#
```

I imagine you're asking for something more involved, though.